Particles loop without dying
I have a box, and inside it, I want the feathers to float and twirl. I also have a curve guide that I need them to follow, along with wind and turbulence to make them look like they’re realistically floating. However, I can’t find a solution to keep the same number of feathers without particles dying or being born. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this? Thank you!
I’m also attaching my screenshot atm.
